# How to fix: 'Git' is not a recognize command from CMD but the git comman works in the GIT CMD CLI?

Tags: windows, git, command-line-interface

My main terminal is the Windows Command Prompt. I am trying to use Git there, but the command is not found. The git command does in fact work in the git terminal. When installing git, I checked the box that said something along the lines of "use git from other terminals than git cmd". Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: If you just installed Git, it might help to reboot (or log out and log in again).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command